# Getting average values from one Array to another Array

Tags: c#

I’m no programmer but I’m learning C# to build a foreign exchange trading system and Arrays are being a struggle…

The problem I have is the following…

I have a one dimensional Array with, let’s say, 100 elements in it.

Now I need to build another one dimensional array with a 10 elements rolling average based on the first Array.

Said in another way, I need to take the elements from the first Array starting in  i = 0 up to i = 9 and average them and save the average in a new array. Than move one step forward and take i = 1 up to i = 10 from the original Array and average them and save the result in the new Array….and so forth….in Excel this would be extremely easy….

My need to have the data in Arrays is because later I will need to compare the last 10 elements rolling average with historical data….

Please, can anyone build a sample code that I can work with?

Many thanks
Paulo

Comment: So us the code you have already tried.

Comment: You might have to do a bit more learning before you try to build a forex trading system.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're not really a site for "Here's what I want to do. Please write the code for me." type questions; we're not a code tutorial site or code writing service. We usually ask that you post an effort to try to solve the problem yourself, and then you can ask a specific question related to that code. There are many C# tutorial sites available via Google and Bing that can show you sample code and exercises for working with arrays. Once you've gone through them and written some of your own code and run into problems, we'll be glad to try and help. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work... Did this on my mac in sublime text so you'll still have to work with. Should get the point though.

```
 public class Foo 
 {
    List<int> main = new List<int>(100);
    List<int> rollingAverages = new List<int>(100);

    public void Add(int score)
    {
        main.Add(score);
        if(main.Count > 10)
        {
            int rollingAverage = AverageLast10();
            rollingAverages.Add(rollingAverage);
        }
    }

    public int AverageLast10()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = main.Count - 10; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sum += main[i];
        }
        return sum / 10;
    }
 }   


Somewhere else in the code

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Add(94);
foo.Add(94);
...
 yadda yadda yadda
```

Comment: Thanks Evan for the suggestion. Found a way around it by creating 2 separate indicators and the final Array is populated with data from the first indicator. kind regards